# Create 2 tables having same column but not a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

( Question is only for a college project as I'm stuck with the requirement)

I want to create 2 tables in SQL Server, say 'table1' and 'table2' in the same database. Both should have a column say 'col1' which is not a primary key.

So how should I create it so that when I insert data into one table, the other gets updated automatically?

**NOTE:** So this is for a college project, we are asked to make a specific type of primary keys so referencing that is not an option, now I have to have same entity in 2 different tables, so is a good idea to somehow reference them, any ideas?

**For eg**, en employee's project details will have his/her empID and the dependants' table will have empID as well. But I cannot make it primary key since that is already defined by the Professor. But updating one should update another as well, does that make sense?

Comment: Storing the same data in two different places is usually a bad idea.  Use a `join` so you can store the data in only one place.

Comment: You don't "create" them that way. You write additional code somewhere that does what you want. You mention "insert", but what about modification and deletion? A trigger can do this to some degree. Choose carefully - this path most likely leads to more problems and work.

Comment: And I note you write "column" but one inserts rows. Another reason to give this idea much more thought.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's the use case?

Comment: it seems that you need one more table, if you explain why exactly you need the same value in two different table the proper solution can be found easier

Comment: To add to Gordon's comment, using a `JOIN` will allow you to make an update affect just one table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please give me an example how can I do that? I have added an example of what I want to do, please go through the Note and example once. Thanks :)

Comment: Use a trigger to mirror the changes in each table

Comment: Thanks, I found your question. I am not being rude. I am telling you helpful things to get you an answer. "exactly look like how you want it" is inappropriate; your post is unclear. Nobody could take what you wrote & write code or an outline other than "use a cascade, trigger and/or transaction". Your description is too vague; it covers too many situations. Look at all the comments--with upvotes--re that. And whatever you mean in detail will be a duplicate. Give code & say where you are stuck. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: "make a specific type of primary keys" & "referencing that" are unclear. Then in "so referencing that is not an option" it's unclear what reasoning "so" refers to. "cannot make it primary key since" is strange--a table has CKs (1 can be picked as PK) regardless of other tables. This post seems to entangle both how to design tables & how to code given a design. Please ask 1 clear specific question re being stuck either designing following a published academic textbook re information modeling & DB design or coding given a design & code (given or specified). PS Querying doesn't need constraints.

Comment: @philipxy I am sorry, I felt it was a bit rude, but thanks a lot for suggesting how to post a question. I will improve onwards. And I found the solution, hopefully from solution you would get what I wanted to do. Also, "make a specific type of primary keys" means it is predefined by Professor, we cannot do anything with it, and its kind of useless for the requirements but we do need to reference entity from each table somehow. Like in below example.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Although that comment really doesn't clarify. PS It's strange that you say that there is some problem with your given PKs because all UNIQUEs & NOT NULLs should be declared that are not implied by declared ones. You still seem confused re PKs. Constraints (PK, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, FK, etc) are not needed for querying, they are for preventing invalid DB states. PKs aren't even needed, the constraint is just UNIQUE NOT NULL. Although DBMSs piggyback other functionality on constraints like indexing & CASCADEs. Glad you seem to have found what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two types of parent-child relationship.

1. **Identifying relationship** : Here, child depends on the parent to identify itself. E.g. Project requires Employee to exist. Here, Project should have EmployeeId part of its primary key or EmployeeId as its primary key. If EmployeeId is primary key of project then, an employee can have only one project.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  EmployeeId INT,
  EmployeeName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeId)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE EmployeeProject
(
  EmployeeId INT,
  EmployeeName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeId),
  FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeId),
)
GO
```

2. **Non-identifying relationship**: Here, child does not depend on the parent to identify itself. E.g. Project can be defined without Employee. Here, Project can have EmployeeId as foreign key. If  EmployeeId is NOT NULL column, then it is mandatory to have an employee. If EmployeeId is NULL column, then it is not mandatory to have an employee.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
  EmployeeId INT,
  EmployeeName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeId)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE EmployeeProject
(
  EmployeeProjectId INT,
  EmployeeName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  EmployeeId INT NOT NULL, -- Can be NULL, if it is not mandatory
  PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeProjectId),
  FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeId),
)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the 2nd solution, as my the business requirement, it suits.

Answer (score 0):

First while creating tables, the entity which is to be refereced as foreign key, make it unique:

Table1:

```
[SIN] int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

Second, in another table where calling [SIN] as FK, put conditions for update and delete:

Table2:

```
[SIN] INT CONSTRAINT [SIN_FK1] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee([SIN]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

By doing this, whenever you update or delete records in Table1, the corresponding record in Table2 will be updated.

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect an exception on update saying the primary key in table 1 cannot be changed as it is referenced by foreign key constraints.

Comment: @kiwiron It worked for me, I tested it. ON UPDATE CASCADE is to make sure you can udpate without getting an exception.

Comment: I think you are technically correct, but in 20 years of database design I have never had the need to change a primary key, let alone Cascade the change to child tables. I strongly recommend you have a competent experienced database designer critique your schema.

Comment: @kiwiron SIN is not a primary key. Primary key is to be in the format <tablename>ID. Our professor is also quite experienced in industry, and he's handed over pretty complex project. Even we're confused haha